# TinyMCE set content with html() after jqGrid is loaded

Tags: jqgrid, tinymce

I have jqGrid and the TinyMCE editor inside my page.

After the grid is loaded I'm selecting the first row.
In the `onSelectRow:` function I set the editor value with `$('#id').html(value_);`. The value is a value inside one of the row cells.

My problem is when the page is loaded for the first row selection I can see the value inside the editor only for 1 second and then it disappears. (When I select the row onclick I can see the value, even if I refresh the page I can see it. It is not working, only for the first time.)

This is my code:

TinyMCE:

```
$('#tinymc_id.tinymce').tinymce({
       theme : "advanced",
       theme_advanced_buttons1 : "cut,copy,paste,|,bold,italic,underline,|,undo,redo,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|" ,
       theme_advanced_buttons2 : "formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|",
       theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
       theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
       theme_advanced_toolbar_align :    "left",
       plugins :                          "paste"
       init_instance_callback : myCustomInitInstance
});

function myCustomInitInstance(ed)
{
    var s = ed.settings;
    var realID = ed.id;
    tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed.getWin(), 'focus', function(e) {
        if($(realID)) {
        }
    });
    tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed.getWin(), 'blur', function(e) {
        if($(realID)) {
        }
    });
}
```

The jqGrid code:

```
   onSelectRow: function(id)
   {
       save_row(lastSel);
       grid.editRow(id,false,'','','','','','','');
       jQuery ('#' + id + '_cell1').focus();
       lastSel=id;
       var _text = grid.getCell(id , "cell2");
       $('#tinymc_id').html(_text);
   },
   loadComplete:function()
   {
       set_selected_row(1);
   }
```

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you probably set the textareas content using html(). But the editor is located inside an iframe (where the textareas content gets showed on init). To set the editor content better use

```
tinymce.get(editor_id).setContent(html_content);
```

Comment: @Thariama: thank's , but it did not work for me , instead i added oninit: to the tinymce init and called $('#tinymc_id').html(_text); inside it. is unsing html() is worng?

Comment: using html is not wrong depending on what '#id' holds, but there are standard methods that the tinymce API provides - it is always safe to use these

Comment: thats what i thought. if you have only one editor at your page you may use the following to make it work: tinymce.editors[0].setContent(value_);

Comment: @Thariama: so it is not o.k to use that in this case? i didn't understand. what if i have 2 editrors in my page?

Comment: then you will need to address them using the editor_id: tinymce.get(editor_id).setContent(html_content);. Thats cause tinymce.editors holds all editors on a page in an array; using tinymce.editors[0] could select the wrong editor then

Comment: @Thariama: o.k thank's.. but still didnot understand what about using just .html() with the specific id , is it o.k?

Comment: this will set the textarea to value_ only, but what you want is to set the editors content to value_

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('textarea'),function() {
           if($(this).val() != "") {
               var value = $(this).val();
               $(this).html(value)
           }
        });
```

try this one if its working